# Logstash Elasticsearch Filter IPv6 Parse Exception

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, logstash, ipv6

I have a threat intel feed indexing black-listed IP addresses to our Elasticsearch cluster, and I want to check log sources (Suricata, Firewall, Packetbeat, etc.) against that index to see if a matching IP address was found. This works perfectly well for IPv4 addresses, but pulling back an IPv6 address is causing a parse failure.

Here is the relative part of the Elasticsearch filter in my Logstash config:

```
filter {
  if [source][ip] {
    elasticsearch {
      hosts => [
        "ESDATA01.Contoso.com:9200",
        "ESDATA02.Contoso.com:9200",
        "ESDATA03.Contoso.com:9200",
        "ESDATA04.Contoso.com:9200",
        "ESDATA05.Contoso.com:9200"
      ]
      index => "threat_feed"
      query => "source.ip:%{[source][ip]}"
      add_field => {"[source][is_malicious]" => "true"}
      add_tag => ["malicious_ip"]
    }
  }
}
```

Any time the query returns an IPv6 address, I get this [excessively long] error in Logstash:

```
Failed to query elasticsearch for previous event {:index=>"threat_feed", :error=>"[400] {\"error\":{\"root_cause\":[{\"type\":\"parse_exception\",\"reason\":\"parse_exception: Encountered \\\" \\\":\\\" \\\": \\\"\\\" at line 1, column 14.\\nWas expecting one of:\\n    <EOF> \\n    <AND> ...\\n    <OR> ...\\n    <NOT> ...\\n    \\\"+\\\" ...\\n    \\\"-\\\" ...\\n    <BAREOPER> ...\\n    \\\"(\\\" ...\\n    \\\"*\\\" ...\\n    \\\"^\\\" ...\\n    <QUOTED> ...\\n    <TERM> ...\\n    <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\\n    <WILDTERM> ...\\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\\n    \\\"[\\\" ...\\n    \\\"{\\\" ...\\n    <NUMBER> ...\\n    \"}],\"type\":\"search_phase_execution_exception\",\"reason\":\"all shards failed\",\"phase\":\"query\",\"grouped\":true,\"failed_shards\":[{\"shard\":0,\"index\":\"threat_feed-2019.08.15-000001\",\"node\":\"sH3qEWb3SJCP6oAoyjLTuA\",\"reason\":{\"type\":\"query_shard_exception\",\"reason\":\"Failed to parse query [source.ip:fe80::a4ab:6b47:c0c2:3594]\",\"index_uuid\":\"IFNFpVtWTcq8kl7iuUqXgA\",\"index\":\"threat_feed-2019.08.15-000001\",\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"parse_exception\",\"reason\":\"parse_exception: Cannot parse 'source.ip:fe80::a4ab:6b47:c0c2:3594': Encountered \\\" \\\":\\\" \\\": \\\"\\\" at line 1, column 14.\\nWas expecting one of:\\n    <EOF> \\n    <AND> ...\\n    <OR> ...\\n    <NOT> ...\\n    \\\"+\\\" ...\\n    \\\"-\\\" ...\\n    <BAREOPER> ...\\n    \\\"(\\\" ...\\n    \\\"*\\\" ...\\n    \\\"^\\\" ...\\n    <QUOTED> ...\\n    <TERM> ...\\n    <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\\n    <WILDTERM> ...\\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\\n    \\\"[\\\" ...\\n    \\\"{\\\" ...\\n    <NUMBER> ...\\n    \",\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"parse_exception\",\"reason\":\"parse_exception: Encountered \\\" \\\":\\\" \\\": \\\"\\\" at line 1, column 14.\\nWas expecting one of:\\n    <EOF> \\n    <AND> ...\\n    <OR> ...\\n    <NOT> ...\\n    \\\"+\\\" ...\\n    \\\"-\\\" ...\\n    <BAREOPER> ...\\n    \\\"(\\\" ...\\n    \\\"*\\\" ...\\n    \\\"^\\\" ...\\n    <QUOTED> ...\\n    <TERM> ...\\n    <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\\n    <WILDTERM> ...\\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\\n    \\\"[\\\" ...\\n    \\\"{\\\" ...\\n    <NUMBER> ...\\n    \"}}}}],\"caused_by\":{\"type\":\"parse_exception\",\"reason\":\"parse_exception: Encountered \\\" \\\":\\\" \\\": \\\"\\\" at line 1, column 14.\\nWas expecting one of:\\n    <EOF> \\n    <AND> ...\\n    <OR> ...\\n    <NOT> ...\\n    \\\"+\\\" ...\\n    \\\"-\\\" ...\\n    <BAREOPER> ...\\n    \\\"(\\\" ...\\n    \\\"*\\\" ...\\n    \\\"^\\\" ...\\n    <QUOTED> ...\\n    <TERM> ...\\n    <FUZZY_SLOP> ...\\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\\n    <WILDTERM> ...\\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\\n    \\\"[\\\" ...\\n    \\\"{\\\" ...\\n    <NUMBER> ...\\n    \"}},\"status\":400}"}
```

The two key points in the error as I see are:

```
"Failed to parse query [source.ip:fe80::a4ab:6b47:c0c2:3594]"
```

```
Cannot parse 'source.ip:fe80::a4ab:6b47:c0c2:3594'
```

Perhaps this is because the colons `:` need to be escaped? If so, how can I escape characters before the data is even returned?

Comment: I took a step back, and I am now thinking it is just the event data that needs the IPv6 address "massaged" before querying. I am not at my system now to test, but I will test later. I am thinking something along the lines of copying the [source][ip] field to a temporary field, using `gsub` to escape any `:`'s, and query that way. I will post back tomorrow after I have had a chance to test.

Comment: Does query => 'source.ip:"%{[source][ip]}"' do any better?

Comment: Thank you @Badger. That looks like it also might be worth a shot (and easier than my idea). I will give that a shot!

Comment: Also, IPv6 Link-Local addresses, such as you have provided, must include the Zone ID because every link uses the same network.

Comment: @RonMaupin I am actually already using the CIDR filter to tag events so I am not looking up private, loopback, or multicast addresses, so that will not be an issue. That address was just a copy/paste from an event that was in front of me.

Comment: That address is an IPv6 Link-Local address (the Link-Local range is `fe80::/10`), and you must use a Zone ID with it.

Comment: Correction... I am not looking up private, loopback, multicast, or link-local addresses. Focus on the query issue, not the specific IP I used in my example. :-P